# Doctrine MongoDB get('doctrine_mongodb')

Tags: symfony, doctrine-odm

I've followed official tutorial on how to integrate MongoDB with Doctrine 2 in Symfony 2.8. [DoctrineMongoDBBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html), and everything went fine until this point:

In my controller I'm trying to push some data in my MongoDB

```
$dm = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager();
$account = new Account($value);
$dm->persist($account);
$dm->flush();
```

It fails on `$this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager();`

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "get" of class
>   "AppBundle\Controller\PlaidController".

I've enabled auto_mapping in config.yml

```
# app/config/config.yml
doctrine_mongodb:
    connections:
        default:
            server: "%mongodb_server%"
            options: {}
    default_database: test_database
    document_managers:
        default:
            auto_mapping: true
```

This is my first encounter with Symfony and Doctrine, so any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller must extend `\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller` class to use `->get()` (and other helper) method.